# How to group cities with similarity in order to perform a regression?

Tags: regression, clustering, multilevel-analysis, propensity-scores, matching

My objective is to understand if the average number of students in the classrooms can lead to better grades in a specific exam to all high school students of the cities in a country.

My country has more than 5000 counties, so I think it would be fair to group those counties in order to perform in a fair way based in the population size, gross domestic profit (gdp) and the number of students of each county.

I was reading about Matching and Propensity Score, however I do not have a treatment/control (as every County invest in education - it is not binary, but some of them invest a high amount).

My first thought was to Cluster them using a technique such as K-Means, and then perform the regression to those group.

I was thinking that as long as I am fine to compare different counties, I could compare Average Number of Students in the Classroom vs Grades and understand if there is a correlation.

I am not sure if it makes sense and I would like to hear from you any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have individual-level grades? And what's your sample size? This sounds like a case where a multilevel model might be useful, incorporating population size, GDP, etc as covariates

Comment: I have all the 5 million grades individually, awhug

Comment: Why do you need/want to cluster them? I would just leave county in as a random effect. A mixed effects model like `grade ~ class_size + (1|school) + (1|county)` seems like a good place to start